# JQuery: dropped divs are sortable only after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When I drop some divs into a sortable pane, I can grab the newly created divs only after the second time I click on them.
I suppose this is a refresh-related issue, but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DvE5Q/
And the code:

```
$(".box").draggable({
   helper: 'clone'
});
$("#left").droppable({
    accept: '.box.out',
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        $(this).append('<div class="box"></div>');
        var droppedBox = $(this).children().last();
        $(droppedBox).html(ui.helper.html());
    }
});
$("#left").sortable();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it your intention that you can drop the same element multiple times?

Comment: Yes, that's why I cloned the elements on the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the attribute `connectToSortable: '#left'`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/DvE5Q/1/

```
$(".box").draggable({
   helper: 'clone',
   connectToSortable: '#left'
});

$("#left").droppable({
    accept: '.box.out',
    drop: function (e, ui) {

    }
});

$("#left").sortable();
```

Comment: Great! Not only it works perfectly, but your solution is elegant in stripping many lines from the code. Thanks Vector.